# Why can't I resume my Compaq 615 machine?

Tags: 12.04, suspend

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Compaq 615 machine about a week ago. I have a problem with suspend/sleep function.

The device suspends and it can be waken up with no problem only in case where i haven't closed the lid.

If i close the lid upon waking up i am encountered by a bright, white flickering screen upon which i have no other option than a button power off to resume my work.
I suspect that there is something incompatible with the ATI HD 3200 and Ubuntu.

Comment: Does switching to a different (text) console help? Can you still log in remotely? (E.g. use SSH to connect to your machine and then reset the display).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my Dual Boot Compaq Presario CQ62. I disabled password when waking from suspend. This solved my problem.